# Change name under project activity on gitlab based on git config user.name

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm new with git and i want to sync my projects in different laptops.
but when i commit or push in gitlab.com no matter from which laptop, in gitlab.com -> project page activities i see the same username i set in gitlab.com profile , however i want different usernames showing up there when i commit from different laptop
i set up 2 ssh keys for each laptops and added in gitlab

i tried using

```
git config user.name
```

and

```
git config --global user.name
```

and

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is currently not possible.

GitLab determines which GitLab user you are, and then prints out your GitLab username.

I think that makes sense, since all those usernames link to your profile, so it would be surprising to have two different display names linking to the same profile.

The best workaround I can think of is to create two different GitLab users. Doesn't it make more sense in your case? Or, you could also add that information to the commit message.

In any case, if you really need that, feel free to open a feature request at: http://feedback.gitlab.com , but personally I don't expect it to get accepted soon.

Comment: Thanks for information. i guess the simple way is mention myself in commit msg